# Call flutter web Google Maps key to index.html

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have saved my google maps API key in constants.dart file located in lib folder. How can i call the API key in constants.dart file from my flutter web folder, index.html?

API key saved in constants.dart:

```
const String googleMapKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
```

I am currently using this for the Google Maps in index.html:

```
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=$googleMapKey"></script>
</head>
```

However the above does not work. Anyone has a solution for this?